# не запускается telegram бот на spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, telegram, telegrambots

Вот гит - https://github.com/DeadSidert/commybot

Ошибок не выдает, спринг запускается нормально, но сам бот не реагирует никак. пробовал загружать на heroku, нормально деплоится, но также не работает.
Код писал по туториалу, поэтому ошибок в коде быть не может. у него все работало...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: твоего бота хакнут) Ты ключ выставил в открытый доступ на Гитхабе

Comment: напиши в своем проекте .gitignore и перезадеплой бота на гит

Comment: @Antonio112009 так у меня есть gitignore, просто на скрине не видно, как он бы решил проблему?

Comment: @Antonio112009 кстати, при попытке закоммитить выдает следующее: ChatBot contains problems
Пока что не нашел ошибок, возможно. где-то с апи что-то там

Comment: Попробуй вначале написать бота на обычном Java, а после перенести код в Spring. Это не решит проблему, но ты хотя бы на Spring не будешь отвлекаться

Comment: + рассмотри данную библиотеку - https://github.com/xabgesagtx/telegram-spring-boot-starter

Comment: @Antonio112009 я пытался писать на чистой Java, но у меня выдает ошибку, связанную с тем. что Телеграм блочен в России, я уже ставил разные прокси. купил себе приватный прокси и все равно ошибка остается...
`окт 22, 2019 1:00:36 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443: Connection reset
окт 22, 2019 1:00:36 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute`

Comment: Переезжай заграницу)

Comment: @Antonio112009 я бы с радостью, но я обычный студент, нет вариантов))

Comment: @Antonio112009 я уже много кого спрашивал, единицы сталкиваются с этой проблемой, прокси в любом случае решает.. Жесть, почему так сложно